# Run Alert when clicking button JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, events, onclick

I am trying to run an alert when clicking at a `<a>` tag.

```js
$('#login-button1').click(function() {
  alert(1234);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <a ui-sref="tabsController.inCio" id="login-button1" class="button button-stable  button-block LoginButton1" href="#/tabsController/home">Login</a>
```

Nothing happens when I click the button.
 I ve tried many other ways to run the alert but none of them seems to have affected the  tag.

Console log does not display any error message.

Comment: Most likely, your browser is blocking alerts. Try a different browser to make sure. Depending on your browser, disabling the block is different, I suppose Google is your best friend.

Comment: This works: https://jsfiddle.net/bensnaize/6zscjf1n/ so maybe you have not included jQuery correctly. Or, as @AndreiGheorghiu says, alerts are perhaps blocked.

Comment: Do you run `$('#login-button1').click` after the element with the id `login-button1` was added to the DOM (e.g in the dom ready callback) you could check this by adding `console.log($('#login-button1').length)` right before adding the click callback, it should be `1`.

Comment: I edited your question turning the code into a snippet. If it doesn't `alert` for you, it's the browser, as I previously suggested. If it does, you haven't included `jQuery` in your page, as @G0dsquad suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that your project is AngularJS.

If you use AngularJS, you can use ng-click directive.

In HTML:

```
<a ui-sref="tabsController.inCio" ng-click="alertMethod()" class="button button-stable  button-block LoginButton1">Login</a>
```

In Controller:

```
    $scope.alertMethod = function () {
        alert(1234);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is supposed to work, everything looks alright, make sure you have jQuery imported correctly. like:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
```

or whatever version of jQuery you are wishing to use, code works fine with above version as seen in this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cceh5f44/)

Comment: Because the console reports no error it is more likely that the `$('#login-button1')` does not find any element. E.g. Because it is executed before the dom is ready. If jquery is not included then the `$(...)` would report an error.

Comment: hmm.. so then its pretty clear that what should be done is to nest that all in `$(document).ready(function(){ ... })`